# Как получить данные JSOn из php в node.js

Tags: node.js

Есть файл `/json.php` с содержимым:

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($user);
```

Как можно получить это содержимое в `node.js`?

Comment: Очевидно нужно сделать запрос к этому скрипту на php?

Comment: @lampa это слишком просто :)

Answer (score 2):

```
http.get('http://yoursite.com/json.php', function(err, response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
});
```